# How can I 'write' an environmental variable as input to a script?

Tags: linux, node.js, shell, command-line

When working with an interactive node script on the linux command line, how can I give it environmental variables as responses?

For instance, there is a certain value I very frequently have to type in as a response to parts of these scripts, and so I just set an environmental variable to contain it, i.e. `my_var = "really long string of names"`.

But when the script prompts me, no matter what I do, it doesn't correctly interpolate the variable. It's as if I had just directly given it `my_var` or `$(my_var)` or `` `$my_var` ``. It always treats it as literal text.

Comment: That depends entirely on how the script reads and interprets user input.

Comment: Oh...well...it's a node script, usually...

Comment: So why is this question tagged `bash` and `shell`?

Comment: Because I wasn't sure if the shell had priority in interpreting my input before it was given to the script. As in, I thought perhaps it would expand `$(var)` and then hand that to node.

Comment: Ah. No, the shell is not involved. Whatever program is running is talking directly to the terminal.

Comment: Tags changed, thank you.

Comment: You could use `expect` to script the input you send to the, er, script: http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Comment: If the process is expecting input from the standard input device, environment variables will not make any difference.  The only thing that you can use is input redirection.

Answer (score 0):

An example using a shell variable in a node script :

bash shell :

```
$ x=foobar
$ nodejs <<EOF
var myvar = '$x'
console.log(myvar)
EOF
```

Result:

```
foobar
```